# Android: add shadow/windowContentOverlay below view

Tags: android, android-layout, header, android-actionbar, shadow

I've manually added a header into my layout. Obviously the shadow (defined in  windowContentOverlay) is placed over the header, but I want it below the header. So how do you add a shadow below the header.

Comment: do you have an image resource to the shadow? in that case you should put the header and the shadow layout in a vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: Well, I use ab_solid_shadow_holo.9.png from the Android source

Comment: But then it won't cover the views below the header, will it?

Comment: if it is transparent, it wont. You could use the opacity xml attribute if it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put ab_solid_shadow_holo.9.png in a layout, something like

```
<LinearLayout ...>
<ImageView ...
android:src=".../ab_solid_shadow_holo.9.png".../>
</LinearLayout>
```

and use it in the header xml like

```
<LinearLayout ...
android:orientation = "vertical">

...your header layout...

<include layout="@layout/action_bar_drop_shadow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

where action_bar_drop_shadow is the name of your xml containing the imageview with the src: ab_solid_shadow_holo.9.png

Comment: Okay, gonna try this and accept this answer when I get it working! Thanks!

Comment: If you want the shadow to overlap the header instead of the content, you should put the header-shadow pair in a FrameLayout and set the shadow's layout_gravity to "bottom", this way it wont take the place from the content of the page, but from the header. Goog luck!